# Return multiple views in blank pages through one ActionResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd appreciate if someone could advise. I have 2 views (NOT partial) and both of them I want to return in blank pages (`target = "_blank"`) at a time.
My submit form looks like:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1",  new { target = "_blank"})
{
//model data

<input type="submit" value = "Go" id="btn"/>
}
```

In my controller I have 2 ActionResults:

```
public ActionResult Action1(MyModel model)
{
return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Action2(string year)
{
ViewBag.year = year;
return View();
}
```

So I want to call both `Action1 and Action2`. `Action1` accepts the model as a parameter and `Action2` accepts some string which could be taken from `MyModel` as well.
Is there any way to do that?
I tried to call `Action2` through jquery on submit button click, but it will not work properly as I want to display the view in new tab.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the reports. I have one ReportViewer (aspx page) with rdlc report where all the data is displayed, and another aspx page with the Header (kind of a title) for the report.

Comment: I will suggest you to create partial view for that

Comment: Thanks but they should be separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want like this.

It might be better to create a new action that returns both the views in separate properties in a single JSON object though - as this is making two calls.

```
$("#Form").on("submit", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/Action1",
        data: $("#Form").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            // do what you need to do with the response here
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/Action2",
        data: { string : $("#Form").find("input#YOUR_INPUT_NAME").val() },
        success: function(response) {
            // do what you need to do with the response here
        }
    });
}
```

Edit:

Assuming that the target="_blank" is working you should be able to create a second hidden form and submit it when the first one is submitted.

```
$("#Form").on("submit", function() {
    var i = $("#Form input#INPUT_ID_HERE").val()
    $("#Form2 input").val(i);
    $("#Form2").submit();        
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the same what I'm doing now. I'm not sure how to diplay this 'response' as a view in a blank page.

Comment: I see the problem. I would probably create two forms, then hide one with css, and then submit the second one when the first is submitted.

Comment: You could get the value from the first form before it is submitted. Updated my post for an example.